# How to find declaration for my typescript/react module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ckeditor

I am very (very) new in frontend technologies, specially react and typescript.

My issue come when trying to do a simple thing that is to use a react component https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5

So I went to the examples and found this:

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react-example/blob/master/package.json

I am trying to include the **ckeditor** with the **ClassicEditor** module

So I added this on my package.json

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^12.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^11.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^11.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^1.1.2",
```

and checking the implementation here https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react-example/blob/master/src/App.js

I need to import the module definition for typescript (I guess)

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';

// NOTE: We use editor from source (not a build)!
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
```

So, this part has this weird note, but happen that does not work in my project (says is missing and cannot find it)

Any idea what else I could do to add it? I tried removing the `/src/classiceditor` part but is still missing.

I made a `npm install` and I am able to see the classiceditor code there with package.json and more... the */src/classiceditor* folder actually exists node_modules with `/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js`

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react does not provide any types and is not typed in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/search?q=%40ckeditor%2Fckeditor5-react&unscoped_q=%40ckeditor%2Fckeditor5-react), so you can not use it in typescript that easily.

If you want to use `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react` with types, you will have to type it yourself.

Example for this :

in your project, declare a file `types/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/index.d.ts`. 
In this file add this (very incomplete) type :

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react' {
    export default class Ckeditor extends React.Component {
        constructor({disabled}: {disabled?: boolean}) // this part needs to be fullfilled with your needs
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to use CKeditor in your react app this way :

```
export function UseCKE() {
    return <Ckeditor disabled={true}/>;
}
```

Comment: I'll add a small example in the answer shortly

Comment: @jpganz18 : exampled added

Comment: Thanks for the update, following your idea I added a file with this declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' { 
    const ClassicEditorBuildLocal: any;

    export = ClassicEditorBuildLocal;
} but when adding ClassicEditorBuildLocal I still get the error.... CkEditor is already imported (and working) but the missing one is only the ckeditor5-build-classic... what could I be missing? the error I get is that  Can't resolve '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

Answer (score 12):

For those who still looking for better solution, I found this solution from [Github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/140#issuecomment-655453105).

you need create file `./types/ckeditor/index.d.ts` and write to

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

for anyone else having the same issue you also try declaring a file types/@ckeditor/index.d.ts and add the following content

```
declare module '@ckeditor/*' {
  const classes: any;
  export default classes;
}
```

the accepted answer did not work for me when dealing with `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`

Answer (score 2):

**For me the working solution was**

1. Add the below lines to `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2015"
    // other options
}
```

2. Creating `typings.d.ts` in typings folder in the app folder

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' {
    const ClassicEditorBuild: any;

    export = ClassicEditorBuild;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue was solved in two steps:

- installing `npm i --save-dev @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic`
- adding a `typings.d.ts` file into my `src` folder with the following declaration:

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react' {
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    import Event from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/eventinfo'
    import { EditorConfig } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/editorconfig'
    import * as React from 'react';
    const CKEditor: React.FunctionComponent<{
        disabled?: boolean;
        editor: typeof ClassicEditor;
        data?: string;
        id?: string;
        config?: EditorConfig;
        onReady?: (editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
        onChange?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
        onBlur?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
        onFocus?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
        onError?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
    }>
    export { CKEditor };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 there are (non-official, third party) [CKEditor types in DefinitelyTyped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-core):

```
npm i --save-dev @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-core
```

In the CKEditor 5 GitHub repo, there's also [ongoing discussion about support for TypeScript](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/504).