# Using ckeditor with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ckeditor

I am getting trouble with the ckeditor when using it with typescript.

I have installed it using `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`

and imported it using:

```js
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```

However, I got the following error: `TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'. '/Users/yifanwang/code/clideo-clone/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/dist/ckeditor.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I have tried to add a `typing.d.ts` file in my project:

```js
declare module "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react" {
    const CKEditor: any;
    export default CKEditor;
}
  
declare module "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic" {
    const ClassicEditor: any;
    export = ClassicEditor;
}
```

But it didn't work as well.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i --save-dev @types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-react
```

and in folder node_modules you will find in @types . And in this folder you create a child folder . It's name ckeditor__ckeditor5-react . and affter that you paste this code .

import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Event from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/eventinfo'
import { EditorConfig } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/editor/editorconfig'
import * as React from 'react';
const CKEditor: React.FunctionComponent<{
disabled?: boolean;
editor: typeof ClassicEditor;
data?: string;
id?: string;
config?: EditorConfig;
onReady?: (editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
onChange?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
onBlur?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
onFocus?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
onError?: (event: Event, editor: ClassicEditor) => void;
}>
export { CKEditor };

Answer (score 0):

For those still interested, this has been answered here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65975437/19121380

Linking to this solution > https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/issues/140#issuecomment-655453105

Simply create a file `./types/ckeditor/index.d.ts` containing :

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
```